# MySQL Dump and Import not preserving encoding?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, mysql

I am trying to copy a table from on MySQL database on a remote machine to another MySQL database on my local machine. I noticed that after importing the dump to my local machine, there were characters like Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ instead of single quotes.

I assumed this was an encoding issue, so I went into both databases and ran `show create table posts`, near the end of both, I saw `CHARSET=utf8`. Also, I ran `file -i` on the dump file, both before and after `scp`ing it to my local machine, and they were both utf8.

However, when I import this file, I get this before:

```
  attendees—policy makers,
```

and after:

```
  attendeesâ€”policy makers,
```

I am not sure why this is happening, everything is using utf8, what am I missing?

EDIT: I am using `mysql Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.75, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)` remotely, and `mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.25a, for osx10.7 (i386)` locally.

Comment: make sure that the mysql monitor is connecting with a utf-8 connection when you're loading up the dump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On both systems you must check that your connection encoding is correct:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'
```

Usually seeing characters like that is the result of double-encoding. Make sure you can match up the connection and client encoding to be exactly the same. There is a number of command line options that can facilitate this, or if you're using a driver or client, something in there can tweak it.

Comment: The connection encoding appears to be latin1, this sounds like what @"Marc B" was suggesting, I'll see if I can change that.